# UseLATEX (for CMake) doesn't accept compiler flags

Tags: compiling, makefile

I'm using [UseLATEX.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/kmorel/UseLATEX) with CMake and it works pretty well except for passing compiler flags.

For example, in the main directory I have a basic TeX file `main.tex`, the `UseLATEX.cmake` file, and this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

project(test NONE)

include(UseLATEX.cmake)

set(LATEX_COMPILER_FLAGS "-jobname=another_name")

set(PDFLATEX_COMPILER pdflatex)
set(LATEX_DEFAULT_BUILD pdf)

add_latex_document(main.tex)
```

I make a directory called `./build`, cd into it, and run `cmake ../` then `make`. The output pdf is still called `main.pdf` and not `another_name.pdf`. It won't accept any compiler flags that I give it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

project(test NONE)

set(LATEX_COMPILER_FLAGS "-jobname=another_name"
    CACHE STRING "Flags passed to latex.")

set(PDFLATEX_COMPILER pdflatex)
set(LATEX_DEFAULT_BUILD pdf)

include(UseLATEX.cmake)

add_latex_document(main.tex)
```

Note the `CACHE STRING "Flags passed to latex."` and the fact that `UseLATEX.cmake` is included *after* setting the variables. You can also use `--jobname=another_name` (i.e., with two dashes; tested on TeX Live 2019).

Comment: That, and, as I've just learned, apparently clearing the build directory is also necessary after a bad compilation.

I should've known that.

Comment: This UseLATEX.cmake is picky! I've already worked with CMake on another project but was a bit surprised to find both conditions I cited as really necessary. Oh well...